# Taking in user input from client in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

So far I'm able to create a socket then bind it to a port and listen for clients. I'm able to accept and have a client connect to the server. I'm not sure how to go about accepting client input. In particular, I need to take GET and HEAD commands from client.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **recv** to read bytes from the socket:

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that this could get tricky pretty fast.  You have to think about whether you want to receive it in a blocking or non-blocking way, and you might have to think about making a buffer for the incoming data in case you don't get an entire line in one read.